# How to extract from a dictionary based on a key value in python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary

Lets say i have a dictionary like this:

```
{
    "test1": [{
            "key1": "123",
            "key2": "456",
            "key3": null,
            "key4": "Book1"
        }, {
            "key1": "123",
            "key2": "456",
            "key3": null,
            "key4": "Book2"
        }, {
            "key1": "12311",
            "key2": "45678",
            "key3": null,
            "key4": "Book1"
        }, {
            "key1": "123",
            "key2": "456",
            "key3": null,
            "key4": "Book4"

        }, {
            "key1": "12322",
            "key2": "45690",
            "key3": null,
            "key4": "Book1"
        }
    ]
}
```

What I want is to have another dictionary in which I have only elements which some key is equal to something (in my case i want to keep all elements where key4 = Book1)
How can I have another dictionary that looks like this:

```
{
    "test1": [{
            "key1": "123",
            "key2": "456",
            "key3": null,
            "key4": "Book1"
        }, {
            "key1": "12311",
            "key2": "45678",
            "key3": null,
            "key4": "Book1"
        }, {
            "key1": "12322",
            "key2": "45690",
            "key3": null,
            "key4": "Book1"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: You need to write code, which you have apparently not even tried to do.

Comment: Hi @ScottHunter, sorry for that, the problem was that i didnt even know where to start, it is not that i havent searched for a solution but everything that i found was not solving my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, there's no such thing as null in python, it's None.
Second, this might work the way you want

```
newDict = {"test1": []}
for i in oldDict["test1"]:
    if i['key4'] == 'Book1':
        newdict["test1"].append(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple one liner:

```py
{"test1": [d for d in data["test1"] if d["key4"] == "Book1"]}
```

Assuming you call your initial dict `data`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @tinu, also this one works